# What textbook/reference should I read in order to answer these questions?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, exterior-algebra

Might be a strange question, but what textbook/reference should I read in order to be able to solve problems like the followings? I only took one class in classical differential geometry, and we covered [chapter one through chapter five from this notes](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~petersen/DGnotes.pdf). But still I do not have sufficient knowledge to solve these problems.

I have taken standard (?) undergraduate level classes in analysis (Apostol, but no measure theory), topology (Greene) and algebra (Hungerford, the introduction one).

> **Example 1**: Let $S^2$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Define map $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ by
>   $$f (x,y,z)\longrightarrow (yz-x,zx-y,xy-z)$$
>   Determine all the singular points of $f$. A point $p$ is singular if if the rank of the differential at $p$ is less than 2.

---

> **Example 2**: Let $n \ge 1$ be an integer and $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ a smooth $n$-dimensional submanifold, which is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. Prove that for any $x_0 \in M$, there exists a line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ satisfying the condition:
>   $$L\cap M = \{x_0\}$$

---

> **Example 3**: Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space with $n \ge 2$. Prove that every element $v \in \wedge^{n−1}V$ can be written as
>   $$v = v_1 \wedge ... \wedge v_{n−1}$$
>   with some elements $v_1, ..., v_{n−1} \in V$ . Here $\wedge^{n−1}V$ denotes the $(n − 1)$-st exterior product of $V$ .

Comment: For starters you need a rigorous course in multivariable analysis, including exterior algebra/differential forms. Then some differential topology (at least learning to apply Sard's Theorem). Consider Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds* and Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*. By the way, there's plenty of good stuff on surface geometry you didn't get to! :(

Comment: @TedShifrin Wow, that sounds like a lot to read. I wonder if I can finish those before February... My professor warned us that the second course would be about christoffel symbols and computation heavy, so I just took other class instead :/

Comment: Did you do all the multivariable material in Apostol (e.g., Inverse and Implicit Function Theorems)?

Comment: @TedShifrin Two years ago, but yes.

Comment: Review that and you should have #1. But there's lots more to learn!

Comment: @TedShifrin  I don't think we ever talked about what a differential is in a rigorous way though?

Comment: Well, get to work:) As another resource I might recommend some of my lectures on rigorous multivariable calculus/analysis available on YouTube. See my profile for the link.

Comment: @TedShifrin Do you have any suggestion for the third problem? I just finished the chapters on tensor product and wedge product of multilinear maps from Munkres' Analysis on Manifold, but still fail to make sense of the question

Comment: You might consider the linear map $V\to\Lambda^nV \cong \Bbb R$ given by wedging with a given element of $\Lambda^{n-1}V$.

Comment: Spivak's *Analysis on Manifolds* is short, sweet, and to the point, and covers the required material.

Answer (score 0):

Example 3 seems a wrong question. How do you produce $dx\wedge dy+dy\wedge dz +dz\wedge dx\in \Lambda^2\mathbb R^{3*}$ as a decomposible term ? Use duals if you prefer $\partial_x\wedge\partial_y+\partial_y\wedge\partial_z+\partial_z\wedge\partial_x$. I like: A comprehensive intro-v1 instead of Spivak's little book. Or a recent text: Loring Tu - An introduction to manifolds.

CORRECTION: I found out that the above form is equal to the decomposible form $(dy-dz)\wedge(dz-dx)$. 
See the answer http://math.rice.edu/~evanmb/math465spring11/math465Grassmannians.pdf for this exercise.